# Emulator Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo cannot be started With Visual Stuido

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator

I am developing android app with Xamarin by using visual studio. I have checked the  windows hyper version and intel X86 but when I try to run the emulator , its not running and showing following errors on console window visual studio.

**'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe"' -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -verbose -feature WindowsHypervisorPlatform -avd Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo -prop monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo
Emulator Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo cannot be started.
Runtime checks completed
Build has been canceled.**

I tried to run the emulator but it showing following error message.

[image]

Here is the full console message.

```
Starting runtime checks
Starting emulator Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo ...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -verbose -feature WindowsHypervisorPlatform -avd Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo -prop monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo1>------ Build started: Project: MobileApp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

WARNING: unexpected '-prop' value ('monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo'), only 'qemu.*' properties are supported
Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
emulator: autoconfig: -skin 768x1280
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir (null)
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\\kernel-ranchu
emulator: Target arch = 'x86'
emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\\ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\\system.img
emulator: Using initial vendor image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\\vendor.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data C:\Users\Khundokar Nirjor\.android\avd\Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo.avd\userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata C:\Users\Khundokar Nirjor\.android\avd\Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo.avd\userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache C:\Users\Khundokar Nirjor\.android\avd\Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo.avd\cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard C:\Users\Khundokar Nirjor\.android\avd\Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo.avd\sdcard.img
emulator: Increasing RAM size to 1536MB
emulator: VM heap size 64MB is below hardware specified minimum of 384MB,setting it to that value
emulator: System image is read only
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:3003: querying file version info API...
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:3011: found kernelbase.dll
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:3019: GetFileVersionInfoSizeW found. On Windows 10?
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:3028: GetFileVersionInfoW found. On Windows 10?
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:3058: VerQueryValueW found. Can query file versions
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:3081: queryFileVersionInfo: path not found: amdvlk64.dll
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:3003: querying file version info API...
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:3081: queryFileVersionInfo: path not found: amdvlk32.dll
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:3003: querying file version info API...
emulator: VERBOSE: System.cpp:3081: queryFileVersionInfo: path not found: vulkan-1.dll
emulator: Found 4 DNS servers: 172.20.10.1 fec0:0:0:ffff::1 fec0:0:0:ffff::2 fec0:0:0:ffff::3
emulator: [FeatureControl] Feature 'WindowsHypervisorPlatform' (15) state set to enabled
emulator: found magic skin width=768 height=1280 bpp=16
emulator: CPU Acceleration: DISABLED
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: Android Emulator requires an Intel processor with VT-x and NX support.  (VT-x is not supported)
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
CPU acceleration status: Android Emulator requires an Intel processor with VT-x and NX support.  (VT-x is not supported)
More info on configuring VM acceleration on Windows:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows
General information on acceleration: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.
emulator: Android emulator version 30.5.5.0 (build_id 7285888) (CL:N/A)
emulator: Found AVD name 'Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo'
emulator: Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator: argv[0]: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE'; program directory: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\
emulator: emuDirName: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\
emulator: Probing for C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\\kernel-ranchu-64: file missing
emulator: try dir C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator
emulator: Trying emulator path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe'
emulator: Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe
emulator: Adding library search path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64'
emulator: Adding library search path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64\gles_angle'
emulator: Adding library search path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64\gles_angle9'
emulator: Adding library search path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64\gles_angle11'
emulator: Adding library search path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64\gles_swiftshader'
emulator: Adding library search path for Qt: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\lib'
emulator: Silencing all qWarning(); use qCWarning(...) instead: QT_LOGGING_RULES=default.warning=false
emulator: Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64\qt\plugins
emulator: Setting Qt to use software OpenGL: QT_OPENGL=software
emulator: Setting QML to use software QtQuick2D: QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext
emulator: Overriding pre-existing bad Qt high dpi settings...
emulator: Quoted param: ["C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe"]
emulator: Quoted param: [-partition-size]
emulator: Quoted param: [512]
emulator: Quoted param: [-no-boot-anim]
emulator: Quoted param: [-verbose]
emulator: Quoted param: [-feature]
emulator: Quoted param: [WindowsHypervisorPlatform]
emulator: Quoted param: [-avd]
emulator: Quoted param: [Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo]
emulator: Quoted param: [-prop]
emulator: Quoted param: [monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo]
emulator: Running :C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe
emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe""
emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "-partition-size"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "512"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[03] = "-no-boot-anim"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[04] = "-verbose"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[05] = "-feature"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[06] = "WindowsHypervisorPlatform"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[07] = "-avd"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[08] = "Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[09] = "-prop"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[10] = "monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo"
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe"' -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -verbose -feature WindowsHypervisorPlatform -avd Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo -prop monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo
Emulator Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo cannot be started.
Runtime checks completed
Build has been canceled.
```

Comment: You could try to disable both [Hyper-V] and [Windows Hypervisor Platform].then restart pc,and enable both [Hyper-V] and [Windows Hypervisor Platform],restart pc again.

Comment: I found only window hypervisor platform and I checked it but I have intel pentium processor in my pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error message gives a pretty explicit message about what is wrong and how to fix it

> emulator: CPU Acceleration: DISABLED emulator: CPU Acceleration
> status: Android Emulator requires an Intel processor with VT-x and NX
> support.  (VT-x is not supported) emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation
> currently requires hardware acceleration! CPU acceleration status:
> Android Emulator requires an Intel processor with VT-x and NX support.
> (VT-x is not supported) More info on configuring VM acceleration on
> Windows:
> https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows

Comment: The intel X86 emulator accelerator already installed